# New Line / Carriage Return in C# Generated Outlook Email

Tags: c#, outlook, newline

Maybe outlook is just formatting this to be the way Outlook wants it to look, bc the code looks good to me, maybe one of you gurus can tell me how to add a carriage return (Have the next previous employer appear on the next line)

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem         
(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);                
string content = string.Empty;
string content = previousEmployer + Environment.NewLine;
//I have also tried this to no avail
//string content = previousEmployer + "\n";
oMsg.HTMLBody = content;
Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("alphaomegaentry.com");
oRecip.Resolve();
oMsg.Save();
oRecip = null;
oRecips = null;
oMsg = null;
oApp = null;
```

Comment: since it's a HTMLBody, have you tried adding a <BR>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If **HTMLBody**  indeed needs to contain HTML, you could try this:

```
string content = string.Format("{0}<br />", previousEmployer);
oMsg.HTMLBody = content;
```

Comment: Hoozah!  That got it! I will accept as soon as this site allows it, it says I have to wait another 5 minutes.

Comment: Good to hear, your English is spot on by the way!